How do i slow down an FPS counter?
So i have this FPS counter here but its counting it way too fast for me:
void Fps::Update(sf::Clock& clock) {
    float currentTime = clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();
    float fps = 1.0f / currentTime;
    std::string fpsAsString = std::to_string((int)fps);
    text.setString("FPS: " + (fpsAsString));
    clock.restart();
}

If i do:
void Fps::Update(sf::Clock& clock) {
    if (clock.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds() >= 100) {
        float currentTime = clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();
        float fps = 1.0f / currentTime;
        std::string fpsAsString = std::to_string((int)fps);
        text.setString("FPS: " + (fpsAsString));
        clock.restart();
     }
}

it shows 9fps constantly which is clearly wrong.
I want it to calculate FPS every 100ms or so, so its slower and more pleasant for the eye but i don't quite understand how to do that.
Could somebody explain how can i do it and why the method i tried doesnt work?
PS. i also tried creating a clock separate from the one used in function like:
void Fps::Update(sf::Clock& clock) {
    sf::clock clock2;
    if (clock2.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds() >= 100) {
        float currentTime = clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();
        float fps = 1.0f / currentTime;
        std::string fpsAsString = std::to\_string((int)fps);
        text.setString("FPS: " + (fpsAsString));
        clock.restart();
    }
}


Every tenth of a second the second example asks for the time in seconds as a floating point number. This should be something close to, but slightly over, 0.1.  Then you divide 1 by this number to always get something close to, but  slightly under, 10. This close to 10 is then converted to an integer by brute force, lopping off the fractional part. If you get 9.999999999, this will be truncated to 9. Thing is, this is just counting time, not frames processed in that time. My recommendation is to look in the graphics library API. There should be a utility function that gets this for you.

My recommendation may be not such a good one. A quick google doesn't turn up such a method in the API. Doesn't mean it doesn't exist, just that it's non-trivial to find via google.

Code 1 "works" because it gets the time since the last call to Update, and uses that time to compute the number of frames that could be processed if all calls to Update took the exact same amount of time. So yes, it's spastic unless you take steps to regulate the frame rate. But If you count he number of frames shown and display that number (times 10) and then reset the count every 100 ms, you should get bot the slower update rate you seem to want and and likely get less all-over-the-place numbers.

thanks for your time @user4581301, but how do i count the number of frames shown? I know its probably easy and understandable but english is not my native language or maybe im just not using my brain... its late here

did you mean:
int frames = 0;
void Fps::Update(sf::Clock& clock)
{
frames++
then set string to frames * 10;
then if (100ms passed)
{
frames = 0;
then reset the clock?
}
}

Add static int frames = 0; at the top of the function. static so that the counter doesn't lose its value on each call to Update. Right after it, and before the if, add frames++;so the counter goes up on every call. If you need more than one instance of the frame counter running you'll need to get a bit smarter, but I don't see that case here.  In theifyou compute and display the fps, restart the timer and as the last statement in theifaddframes = 0`.

Note that the above is pretty gross, FPS is always a multiple of ten, for example. You can do better, but this is a decent start.

FPS is "frames divided by time". In the first, the 1.0f is correct since it is the number of frames since you last updated the counter. In the second, you need to count the number of frames between fps updates and divide that number instead.

@user4581301 one problem with that method i found is that it looses accuracy the faster you want your fps to calculate for example if i want to calculate fps every 100ms then i have to multiply it by 10, but then it gives me fps in 10s (150,140,130, 60,70 etc.). But if i want it to calculate fps every 1 second its just multiplied by 1 so its as accurate as it can get.  This method works goood but for 1 second which is fine to me, but i wonder how can i write an easy code that calculates fps accurately no matter the speed? is this possible?

@molbdnilo Actually if i set fps limit to something higher like 400, it looks like it swings way past it and stays around 500 instead of 400.
Is there a reason for that and is there any way i can fix it?

If you're using setFramerateLimit, the SFML tutorial says "it is not 100% reliable, especially for high framerates". There is no reason to have a framerate in the several hundreds.

you could control the update with a fixed timestep like this:
int main()
{
    window.create(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML window");

    sf::Clock clock;
    sf::Time previous;
    sf::Time current;
    sf::Time elapsed;

    float FPS = 60.0f;
    float deltaTime = 1.0f / FPS;
    float frameTime = 0.0f;
    float lag = 0.0f;

    clock.restart();
    previous = clock.getElapsedTime();

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        current = clock.getElapsedTime();
        elapsed = current - previous;
        previous = current;

        frameTime = elapsed.asSeconds();
        
        handleInput();

        lag += frameTime;
        while (lag >= deltaTime) {
            update();
            
            lag -= deltaTime;
        }

        render();
    }

    return 0;
}

This will limit the update time-step while not affecting input handling and rendering.
This implementation is based on Robert Nystrom's solution from his book Game Programming Patterns. You can check out his explanation here https://www.gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html
